# Finding closest tr...does script search for ancestor?

Tags: javascript

Little bit confused. I'm trying to search the contents of the iframe and click the link within . The link is 'Attack'.

```
<script>
setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(); }, 1000); // 1 seconds, e.g.

$(document).ready(function() {
$('a[href*="5562089"]', $("game").contents()).closest('tr').find('.fightActionInnerInner').parent("a").trigger("clic    k");
});
</script>


<iframe src="http://vl.storm8.com/hitlist.php" width="100%" height="800px" id="game"></iframe>
```

Here is the HTML within the iframe that I want to interact with.

```
<td class="fightMobster">
    <div>
        <a href="/profile.php?puid=5562089&formNonce=34947b8ffc73e8ceafabae71…94f&setTab1Badge=&h=2d55f5781bfe888b47d7f5c9dbc27df2f663347f">
            Lord Pookie
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        Lvl 212 Daywalker
    </div>
</td>
<td class="fightSp"></td>
<td class="fightMobSize">
    <span class="cash">
        <span style="white-space: nowrap;">
            <img width="15" height="14" style="padding-right:2px" src="http://static.storm8.com/zl/images/flesh.png?v=330"></img>
            15,300
        </span>
    </span>
</td>
<td class="fightSpLg"></td>
<td class="fightAction">
    <script>
        function fsb99995143() {
            var b=…
    </script>
    <a onclick="return fsb99995143();" href="/hitlist.php?tab=fight.php&action=fight&hitlistId=99995143&f…1b4b9390bee9a194f&h=284e4fe4946e6fb8af3a662f4583454eebc8bd23">
        <div class="fightActionInner">
            <div class="fightActionInnerInner">
                Attack
            </div>
```

I'm confused. The script refreshes the page, but doesn't seem to want to click the link that's there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to replace "ready" with "load" in $(document).ready

Comment: Well you have a timeout that is reloading the page....seems weird.

Comment: @FrederikWitte Thanks for your reply, but still not change after that I'm afraid :(

Comment: @epascarello True, I do. This is because I need the page to refresh, then search for the link, then refresh, search and so on.

Comment: And I do not see any text with "5562089" in it. In your code. I see a link with it in it.

Comment: @epascarello Fourth line down in the HTML...

Comment: where is `tr` with `.fightActionInnerInner` class in your code ??

Comment: @epascarello You are correct, it searches for the link, and then finds the next class of 'fightActionInnerInner' and clicks the link within that class.

Answer (score 0):

The following line is useless so remove it:

```
document.getElementById('game').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
```

First you are not looking at the code in the iframe, you are selecting elements in the current window. So you need to change to the code look at the iframe.

Second, the [contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) looks at the text, not the attributes. You want to use an [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).

Change

```
$('a:contains("5562089")')
```

to

```
$('a[href*="5562089"]', $("game").contents())
```

and I am not sure why you are clicking the div and not the actual link itself.

```
$('a[href*="5562089"]', $("game").contents()).closest('tr').find('.fightActionInnerInner').parent("a").trigger("click");
```

and hopefully the iframe is fully loaded when you try to click it. And if the name of the function does not change you can just call the function

```
$('#game')[0].contentWindow.fsb99995143();
```

Comment: I altered my code to match yours, but still no change. Is it because it's searching UP the page rather than DOWN?

Comment: Still no change after latest alteration :/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your efforts, much appreciated, but it still doesn't want to click the link within the iframe. :(

Comment: Just found out something. The page refreshes as expected. I can see the link appear in the iframe. The script doesn't click the 'Attack' link, but inbetween refreshes, if I click it manually, it DOES continue to click it, but just not the first time :/

Comment: My guess you need to wait for the iframe to load fully and the refresh should probably wait until the iframe is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for click on link if link contain something :

```
var th = $("a").attr("href");
var st = "5562089";
if(th.indexOf(st)!=-1){
    //Do your implementation
}
```